# App won´t show WebView with my Instagram feed

Tags: android, instagram, velo

I am currently trying to create a WebView that shows my Instagram posts but the WebView won´t show any media (photos and videos)

I created an Instagram feed with my pictures only with WIX editor but nothing really showed up besides a navigation bar which had nothing to do with the feed. Also on WIX editor, i created a standard gallery function in which you can upload pictures from your computer but the media inserted here isn´t visible too. I just added the permission "INTERNET" in the manifest file.

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://dawdjobe5.wixsite.com/meinewebsite");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();}
}}



<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I expect to get the feed with it´s basic funcionality (enlarge the pictures on click and see the number of likes and comments) but right now the WebView is scrollable but that has ahrdly any relation to the Instagram feed being invisible or something in that direction.

Comment: JavaScript isn't enabled yet.

Comment: Just read https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: @ZUNJAE Thank you, it worked. Unfortunately, the screen freezes every time i press on one of the pictures. I read that customizing the WebChromeClient helps if i want to open new windows in a WebView because it is ignored within the standard settings. I don´t really understand how customize that because the instructions in Android developers aren´t very beginner-friendly sometimes.

Comment: There are more settings to explore in WebSettings. Please note that a naked WebView is... naked. you need to modify a lot by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just enable JavaScript in your webview websettings like this and it will work:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

than load your url:

```
webView.loadUrl("https://dawdjobe5.wixsite.com/meinewebsite");
```

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. Unfortunately, i still cannot enlarge the pictures in the feed to show the number of likes and comments.  The app even freezes when i press on a picture.

Comment: Hmm.. I think you should add some kind of JavaScriptInterface and use html from this page. Worked something similar in the past, but don't have time to try it now. Sorry